# Identify locations in multiple columns where values change, grouped by subject and experiment, PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

This is an update to a previous post. I am having a problem sorting within a group. Thanks to @IanThompson for his help earlier.

Using the following code, I am attempting to group by Subject ID and Experiment, and then create a column called 'color' which is ordered by the 'Trial' associated with it. 'Trial' corresponds to the row at which a value in one of the color columns (e.g. 'color1', 'color10') changes to silver.

My problem is that I am unable to sort within the Subject, ExperimentName group by Trial. I have tried .sort_values(by=['Trial']), however that seems to not be sorting it *within* the group, which is what I wish to do.

I would like the output to look exactly as @IanThompson's does in this post.

Here is the relevant code, followed by the dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100)
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_clipboard()

# melt it into shape
df2 = df1.melt(id_vars = [
    'ExperimentName',
    'Subject',
    'Trial'
], value_vars = [
    'color1',
    'color10',
    'color11',
    'color12',
    'color13',
    'color14',
    'color15',
    'color16',
    'color17',
    'color18',
    'color19',
    'color2',
    'color20',
    'color21',
    'color22',
    'color23',
    'color24',
    'color25',
    'color26',
    'color27',
    'color28',
    'color29',
    'color3',
    'color30',
    'color31',
    'color32',
    'color33',
    'color34',
    'color35',
    'color36',
    'color4',
    'color5',
    'color6',
    'color7',
    'color8',
    'color9',
], var_name = 'color')

# filter value to 'silver'
df2[df2.value == 'silver'].groupby([
    'ExperimentName',
    'Subject',
    'color'
]).agg({'Trial' : 'min'}).sort_values(by=['Trial'])
```

Here is the dataset:

```
ExperimentName  Subject Trial   Background  color1  color10 color11 color12 color13 color14 color15 color16 color17 color18 color19 color2  color20 color21 color22 color23 color24 color25 color26 color27 color28 color29 color3  color30 color31 color32 color33 color34 color35 color36 color4  color5  color6  color7  color8  color9  ColorChange RespSlide.RT    RespSlide.RTTime
FacFac  91  1   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    red blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    red purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   949 33133
FacFac  91  2   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    red purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   1019    45197
FacFac  91  3   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   5596    57453
FacFac  91  4   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  red red red red red 0   1506    67157
FacFac  91  5   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  red red red red 0   1061    74908
FacFac  91  6   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  red red red 0   2350    87092
FacFac  91  7   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  red red 0   1067    95404
FacFac  91  8   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  red 0   1341    103924
FacFac  91  9   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1188    112484
FacFac  91  30  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   548 308799
FacFac  91  31  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   547 317927
FacFac  91  32  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   521 324831
FacFac  91  33  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   502 330759
FacNo   91  1   bgA.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   982 93293
FacNo   91  2   bgA.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1215    102005
FacNo   91  3   bgA.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   632 110301
FacNo   91  37  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   1385    393502
FacNo   91  38  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   1141    400438
FacNo   91  39  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   0   0
RandFac 92  14  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    red purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1176    203938
RandFac 92  15  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  red purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1204    229338
RandFac 92  16  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1095    241689
RandFac 92  36  bgA.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1516    696759
RandFac 92  37  bgA.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   0   0
RandNo  92  1   bgC.jpg blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1340    25909
RandNo  92  2   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1600    46693
RandNo  92  3   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk 0   982 53821
RandNo  92  4   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk 0   1020    68052
RandNo  92  5   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk 0   1703    101420
RandNo  92  6   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk 0   746 108675
RandNo  92  7   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  0   1341    118699
RandNo  92  8   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1194    126731
RandNo  92  9   bgC.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   766 144995
RandNo  92  10  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   986 154610
RandNo  92  11  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   838 172970
RandNo  92  12  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1871    181266
RandNo  92  13  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1711    191418
RandNo  92  14  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1087    214865
RandNo  92  15  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1502    237153
RandNo  92  16  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   993 260616
RandNo  92  17  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1245    276944
RandNo  92  18  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1190    285768
RandNo  92  19  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1087    297759
RandNo  92  20  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   798 319959
RandNo  92  21  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   837 329310
RandNo  92  22  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   850 348614
RandNo  92  23  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   987 360046
RandNo  92  24  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   626 388621
```

Old post:
Here is the relevant code so far:

```
data = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
data.filter(like='color').isin(['silver'])
boolSilver = data.filter(like='color').isin(['silver']).astype(int)
```

Comment: it would be a lot more useful to post the example data.xlsx instead of a jpg of this data, which can't be loaded by people trying to help you

Comment: Hey, @JonathonMcMurray, thanks (!); how can I post the Data.xlsx? Tried looking up how to insert it into this post, but haven't found anything...  The data is currently in xlsx format and that's what I've loaded into python. Is there a way to attach the file to posts, or to get the data formatted into code that can be pasted in the post?

Comment: @Mika copy/paste a subset of the data from your `.xlsx` file in a code block

Comment: Hey, @IanThompson, thank you. I'm not sure I did it correctly, though. Still looks wonky to me. Is that what you meant? I copied some of the cells from my dataset, pasted them, and then highlighted them and clicked the "Code" icon.

Comment: Looks wonky but should work. Will lyk when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

## Edit with new data

```
# data
'''
ExperimentName  Subject Trial   Background  color1  color10 color11 color12 color13 color14 color15 color16 color17 color18 color19 color2  color20 color21 color22 color23 color24 color25 color26 color27 color28 color29 color3  color30 color31 color32 color33 color34 color35 color36 color4  color5  color6  color7  color8  color9  ColorChange RespSlide.RT    RespSlide.RTTime
FacFac  91  1   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    red blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    red purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   949 33133
FacFac  91  2   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    red purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   1019    45197
FacFac  91  3   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    red red red red red red 0   5596    57453
FacFac  91  4   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  red red red red red 0   1506    67157
FacFac  91  5   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  red red red red 0   1061    74908
FacFac  91  6   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  red red red 0   2350    87092
FacFac  91  7   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  red red 0   1067    95404
FacFac  91  8   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  red 0   1341    103924
FacFac  91  9   bgA.jpg silver  teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    teal    blue    silver  blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    blue    purp    purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1188    112484
FacFac  91  30  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   548 308799
FacFac  91  31  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   547 317927
FacFac  91  32  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   521 324831
FacFac  91  33  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    purp    purp    purp    purp    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   502 330759
FacNo   91  1   bgA.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   982 93293
FacNo   91  2   bgA.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1215    102005
FacNo   91  3   bgA.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   632 110301
FacNo   91  37  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   1385    393502
FacNo   91  38  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   1141    400438
FacNo   91  39  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  2   0   0
RandFac 92  14  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    red purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1176    203938
RandFac 92  15  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  red purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1204    229338
RandFac 92  16  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  purp    blue    blue    silver  red purp    teal    purp    red red purp    teal    red teal    silver  teal    teal    purp    teal    teal    blue    blue    silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1095    241689
RandFac 92  36  bgA.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1516    696759
RandFac 92  37  bgA.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   0   0
RandNo  92  1   bgC.jpg blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1340    25909
RandNo  92  2   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk 0   1600    46693
RandNo  92  3   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk 0   982 53821
RandNo  92  4   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk 0   1020    68052
RandNo  92  5   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk 0   1703    101420
RandNo  92  6   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk 0   746 108675
RandNo  92  7   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  0   1341    118699
RandNo  92  8   bgC.jpg silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1194    126731
RandNo  92  9   bgC.jpg silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   766 144995
RandNo  92  10  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   986 154610
RandNo  92  11  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   838 172970
RandNo  92  12  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1871    181266
RandNo  92  13  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1711    191418
RandNo  92  14  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1087    214865
RandNo  92  15  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1502    237153
RandNo  92  16  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   993 260616
RandNo  92  17  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1245    276944
RandNo  92  18  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1190    285768
RandNo  92  19  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   1087    297759
RandNo  92  20  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   798 319959
RandNo  92  21  bgC.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   837 329310
RandNo  92  22  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   850 348614
RandNo  92  23  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   987 360046
RandNo  92  24  bgB.jpg silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  blk blk blk blk blk blk blk silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  silver  0   626 388621
'''

# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# read data
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# melt into shape
df1 = df.melt(id_vars = [
    'ExperimentName',
    'Subject',
    'Trial'
], value_vars = df.columns.tolist()[4:-3], var_name = 'color')

# filter to silver, group and agg, swap indices and sort
df1[df1.value == 'silver'].groupby([
    'Subject',
    'ExperimentName',
    'color'
]).agg({
    'Trial' : 'min'
}).reset_index('color').set_index('Trial', append = True).sort_index()
```

[image: output]

Comment: Hey, All, thank you so much for your advice so far!  Yes, @Ian Thompson, that is very similar to what I am looking for! I want to have the order number (so first = 1, second = 2) attached to the color. Is it possible for you to post the code or tell me how you did it?

Comment: @Mika what do you mean "order number (so first = 1, second = 2) attached to the color"? Like the order based on `Trial`? For example, (NumFac,91) would be first = color1, second = color10, third = color2?

Also, my code is posted.

Comment: Does my edit above work for what you need? Or if it doesn't, could you post what your desired output should look like?

Comment: I'm sorry, my earlier comment was unclear. A color change to silver represents a click, and yes, it corresponds to Trial (or the row index, I suppose?). color2 is the 2nd 'click'/color change because it changes to silver at trial 2. color1 is first because it is silver throughout. In the final output I have a column called "OrderClicks" which is your 'color' column in the output- a list of the color column names ordered by when they were clicked.
The output you posted is it - I'll just rename the 'color' column 'OrderClicks'.

I also see the code now - didn't scroll far enough lol.

Comment: This will be very helpful because there are some other things I want to do with this dataset that are similar to the process you provided code for. Now I have an idea of how to do approach these other things. Many, many thanks, @Ian Thompson.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer as correct.

Comment: Hey there, @Ian Thompson. Thanks again for your help. It's interesting because the code that you provided works well on the original sample dataset, but not on this new one. It does not sort the 'color' column by the 'Trial' column. As mentioned above, I've tried sort_values() and several other ways, but I'm stumped. I thought it might be because the color columns in the new dataset are in a different order than the ones in the sample set you worked on, but despite changing the order in the script @ the value_vars, no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mika what isn't working? I tried with your new data and it works for me. Posting new code for simplicity. See edits above

Comment: Hmm, so with .reset_index('color').set_index('Trial', append = True).sort_index() it works. Previously, for Subject 91 FacFac, it had not sorted by the color column, but for all others it had. 

Hmm, so if I understand what's going on here, it was the resetting of the index to the color column, and then sorting in ascending order that is ordering them. 

.reset_index('color').set_index('Trial', append = True).sort_index()

Now, what is .set_index doing that sorting by the color column is not doing? In other words, why are we resetting the index to 'color' and then setting it to 'Trial'?

Comment: Resetting the color takes it out of the index while setting Trial puts it in the index. That way when we sort the index it also sort by trial within each level.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I get it. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: It would work the same as resetting the entire index and then sorting values on subject, experiment, trial; keeping them in the index makes it look nicer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want and the best way to you.

I first convert the data from wide to long format, then make use of `.shift()` to find the colour of the previous stage (lag value) and check if there is any colour change to silver.

```
import pandas as pd

# Read Data
sample_data = pd.read_csv('...\\sample_data.txt', sep='\t')
colnames = sample_data.columns

# Convert Data From Wide to Long Format
df_long = pd.wide_to_long(sample_data, stubnames='color', i=colnames[0:3], j='order')
df_long = df_long.reset_index()
df_long.order = pd.to_numeric(df_long.order)  # Sorting of str and int variables are different
df_long.sort_values(by=['ExperimentName', 'Subject', 'Trial', 'order'], inplace=True)
df_long['l_ExperimentName'] = df_long.ExperimentName.shift()
df_long['l_Subject'] = df_long.Subject.shift()
df_long['l_Trial'] = df_long.Trial.shift()
df_long['l_color'] = df_long.color.shift()

# Find if there is any colour change to silver within the same trial
df_long['i_silver'] = df_long.color == 'silver'
df_long['i_lag_not_silver'] = df_long.l_color != 'silver'
df_long['i_change_to_silver'] = (df_long.i_silver & 
                                df_long.i_lag_not_silver & 
                                (df_long.ExperimentName == df_long.l_ExperimentName) & 
                                (df_long.Subject == df_long.l_Subject) & 
                                (df_long.Trial == df_long.l_Trial))
df_change_to_silver = df_long.loc[df_long.i_change_to_silver == True, ['ExperimentName', 'Subject', 'order', 'Trial', 'l_color', 'color']]
```

Output:

```
# Print the changes
print(df_change_to_silver)

    ExperimentName  Subject  Trial  order l_color   color
206         FacFac       92      3     15    teal  silver
215         FacFac       92      4     15    teal  silver
224         FacFac       92      5     15    teal  silver
57          NumFac       91      2     10     red  silver
66          NumFac       91      3     10     red  silver
75          NumFac       91      4     10     red  silver
84          NumFac       91      5     10     red  silver
226         NumFac       92      1      2    pink  silver
102          NumNo       91      2     10   black  silver
111          NumNo       91      3     10   black  silver
120          NumNo       91      4     10   black  silver
129          NumNo       91      5     10   black  silver
147        RandFac       91      2     10    blue  silver
156        RandFac       91      3     10    blue  silver
165        RandFac       91      4     10    blue  silver
174        RandFac       91      5     10    blue  silver
```

Comment: Hey, @kitman0804, thanks for the help. What I need though is an order number per color column. From this, I would like to create a column called "OrderClicks" which will be a list of the color column names ordered by when they were clicked. So, for Subject 91 in Experiment FacFac: color1 was clicked first (meaning the value in the input color1 column changes from teal to silver at an earlier trial/row # than the other color columns), it will be the first in the new OrderClicks column of the output. It will be followed by color2, which had the second color-to-silver change.